# losing stdout in R console on Mac OS X

Tags: r, interactive, sweave

I'm working on a big Sweave document/script on a Mac OS X system, R version 2.9.2. Under some circumstances, it appears as if Sweave is redirecting stdout, so that `x <- 1; print(x)` gives nothing at all. (The console is still running, as `plot(x)` pops up a plot as normal.) So, two questions:

1. How do I force stdout to go back to the console, and,
2. Why does Sweave do this, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, with extensive use of [RSeek](http://RSeek.org). The `sink()` function redirects the console to a file. `sink(NULL)` cancels the redirection. Still not entirely sure why Sweave sets up a sink. I suspect that bugs in my code were causing Sweave to abort without canceling the sink.

Comment: it happens to me often, and i usually just restart the R session. Now I have a better solution, thanks!